# Where is Frame.Navigate(Uri uri) method?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

Im trying to create custom navigation manager for my WinRT app. All I want is a simple class I can use in MVVM that would enable me creation of navigation logic within XAML. My idea looks like this:

```
<Button Content="Details" Command="{Binding Navigate}" 
                          CommandParameters="Page2.xaml"/>
```

In order to do this I found out there is `Navigate(Uri uri)` in the `Frame` class. With this method my dream would come true. The problem is there is no such method. The only method I can call on `Frame` is `Navigate(Type type)`.

Does anybody know, how can I call [this `Navigate(Uri uri)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.navigate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in WinRT?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are on the right track. Instead of the `Uri` you are supposed to use the type of the page class you are trying to navigate to.

Try something like this:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(YourPageClass));
```

Comment: Thanks Scott for correcting the format. Not used to the tags yet ;)

Answer (score 0):

This method is in System.Windows.Controls.Frame assembly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.aspx